# How to move and rotate the marker along with the current location?

Tags: kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

This is how I have been trying to implement the `GoogleMaps` in Jetpack compose.

*Things I have done.*

1. Live location update.
2. Move Camera.
3. Custom Marker.

```
                    GoogleMap(
                        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                        properties = MapProperties(isMyLocationEnabled = true),
                        uiSettings = MapUiSettings(
                            compassEnabled = true,
                            indoorLevelPickerEnabled = false,
                            myLocationButtonEnabled = true
                        )
                    ) {
                        viewModel.origin?.let { userLocation ->
                            GoogleMarkers(origin = userLocation, destination = destination)
                        }
                        // origin?.let { GoogleMarkers(it, destination) }
                        directionsResult.value?.routes?.forEach { route ->
                            Polyline(
                                points = route.overviewPolyline.decodePath().map {
                                    LatLng(it.lat, it.lng)
                                },
                                color = Color(0xFF2196F3),
                                jointType = JointType.DEFAULT,
                                width = 12f
                            )
                        }
                    }
```

This is how I am implementing Markers:

```
@Composable
    fun GoogleMarkers(origin: LatLng, destination: LatLng) {
        val latLongOrigin = LatLng(origin.latitude, origin.longitude)

        Marker(
            state = rememberMarkerState(position = latLongOrigin),
            title = "Origin",
            snippet = "Origin of the location",
            icon = bitmapDescriptorFromVector(LocalContext.current, R.drawable.car, 160, 160),
            rotation = bearingBetweenLocations(
                latLongOrigin,
                LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude)
            ).toFloat()
        )

        Marker(
            state = rememberMarkerState(position = destination),
            title = "Lotus Temple",
            snippet = "The Lotus temple",
            icon = bitmapDescriptorFromVector(
                LocalContext.current,
                R.drawable.destination,
                150,
                150
            )
        )
    }
```

The problem is that the location is updating live, but the marker isn't moving. The marker stays still.
Could anyone please help me to rotate and move the marker along with the current location?

Comment: Where is the method that updates the marker when the live location updates?